# eval-when-compile and eval-and-compile identical definitions?

Tags: elisp-macros, byte-compilation

How can `eval-when-compile` and `eval-and-compile` have different behavior if their definitions are identical?

From byte-run.el:

```el
(defmacro eval-when-compile (&rest body)
  ;; ... documentation string omitted ...
  (declare (debug (&rest def-form)) (indent 0))
  (list 'quote (eval (cons 'progn body) lexical-binding)))

(defmacro eval-and-compile (&rest body)
  ;; ... documentation string omitted ...
  (declare (debug (&rest def-form)) (indent 0))
  (list 'quote (eval (cons 'progn body) lexical-binding)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can `eval-when-compile` and `eval-and-compile` have different behavior if their definitions are identical?

The hint is in the commentary in the definition of `eval-and-compile`:

```el
;; When the byte-compiler expands code, this macro is not used, so we're
;; either about to run `body' (plain interpretation) or we're doing eager
;; macroexpansion.
```

Indeed, it's not the body of these macros that defines their semantics, but the environment in which they're expanded during byte-compilation.  The two semantics are differentiated in `byte-compile-initial-macro-environment`:

```
byte-compile-initial-macro-environment is a variable defined in `bytecomp.el'.

Its value is shown below.

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

The default macro-environment passed to macroexpand by the compiler.
Placing a macro here will cause a macro to have different semantics when
expanded by the compiler as when expanded by the interpreter.

Value:
((declare-function . byte-compile-macroexpand-declare-function)
 (eval-when-compile . #f(compiled-function
                         (&rest body)
                         #<bytecode 0x914a391b97fc68e>))
 (eval-and-compile . #f(compiled-function
                        (&rest body)
                        #<bytecode 0x1395261de4da407b>))
 (with-suppressed-warnings . #f(compiled-function
                                (warnings &rest body)
                                #<bytecode -0xadad30c834fbff0>)))
```

Here's the current environment for `eval-when-compile`:

```el
(lambda (&rest body)
  (let ((result nil))
    (byte-compile-recurse-toplevel
     (macroexp-progn body)
     (lambda (form)
       ;; Insulate the following variables against changes made in the
       ;; subsidiary compilation.  This prevents spurious warning
       ;; messages: "not defined at runtime" etc.
       (let ((byte-compile-unresolved-functions
              byte-compile-unresolved-functions)
             (byte-compile-new-defuns
              byte-compile-new-defuns))
         (setf result
               (byte-compile-eval
                (byte-compile-top-level
                 (byte-compile-preprocess form)))))))
    (list 'quote result)))
```

And that for `eval-and-compile`:

```el
(lambda (&rest body)
  (byte-compile-recurse-toplevel
   (macroexp-progn body)
   (lambda (form)
     ;; Don't compile here, since we don't know whether to compile as
     ;; byte-compile-form or byte-compile-file-form.
     (let ((expanded (macroexpand-all form macroexpand-all-environment)))
       (eval expanded lexical-binding)
       expanded))))
```

It is not entirely uncommon to have macros whose body does very little, but whose macroexpansion is treated specially.  Another example in addition to the forms listed above is the `declare` form, whose body is `nil` but whose macroexpansion results in the setting of function properties.